# Expectation of joint distribution of uniform random variables

Tags: probability, expectation

Can you provide an example of a joint distribution of $X,Y$ exchangeable random variables for which $\operatorname{E}[X/Y]<\infty$ with $X,Y\sim U(0,1)$ and $P(X=Y)=0$.

I've tried to find one but i think that $\operatorname{E}[X/Y]$ exists only if $P(X=Y)=1$ otherwise the integral diverges and the expectation does not exist.

Comment: If one drops the requirement of exchangeability, then this does it:
$$\begin{align}
X \sim {} &\operatorname{Uniform}(0,1) \\[10pt]
Y = {} & \begin{cases} 2X & \text{if } 2X<1, \\ 2X-1 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}
\end{align}$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy In your example, $Y$ is entirely a function of $X$ and other conditions are satisifed. But I get $E[X/Y]=\int ^{1/2} _0 \dfrac {x}{2x}dx + \int ^{1} _{1/2} \dfrac {x}{2x-1}dx$, and the second term is still unbound, or my calculation not correct?

Comment: @novavita : Sorry -- I should have interchanged $Y$ and $X.$ As it is, you can say that $\operatorname{E}(Y/X) < \infty. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy yeah, now it works. excellent idea!

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
X \sim {} &\operatorname{Uniform}(0,1) \\[10pt]
Y = {} &
\begin{cases} \frac 3 2 - X & \text{if } \frac 1 2 < X< 1 \\[10pt]
\frac 3 4 - X & \text{if } \frac 1 4 < X < \frac 1 2 \\[10pt]
\frac 3 8 - X & \text{if } \frac 1 8 < X < \frac 1 4 \\[10pt]
\text{and so on.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Then $Y$ also has the same uniform distribution as $X,$ and the distribution of $(Y,X)$ is the same as that of $(X,Y)$ (exchangeability) and the values of $X/Y$ and $Y/X$ remain between $1/2$ and $2$ and so have finite expectation, and $\Pr(X=Y)=0.$